# Get process output while process is running in Python

Tags: python, subprocess, raspberry-pi4

I am trying to write a little program in Python (version 3.7.3) with which I can get the out stream of another program while it is running. To emulate this condition I write a very trivial program in python that print a string every 10 seconds.

writecycle.py

```
import time

while(1):
    print("test process")
    time.sleep(10)
```

In the program that I am trying to write I run this process and I try to get the output

mainproc.py

```
import time
import subprocess

proc=subprocess.Popen(["python","writecycle.py","&"],stdout=subprocess.PIPE,encoding='UTF-8')
print("start reading output")

while(1):
    strout=proc.stdout.read()
    print("_"+strout)
    time.sleep(10)
```

but I cannot get further the "start reading output" message. The program get "stuck" on the *proc.stdout.read()* command.

I red some solution that suggest to use *subprocess.communicate()* but I think that this command does not fit my needs since it wait the process to be terminate for reading the out stream.
Someone else suggest to use *subprocess.poll()* but I still get stuck on the *proc.stdout.read()* command.

I tried using *bufsize=1* or *0* in the *Popen* command with no results, or using *readline()* but nothing.

I don't know if this helps but I am using a Raspberry Pi4 with Raspbian Buster.

Comment: `stdout.read()` is not going to return until the subprocess finishes (which is never, in this case).  `stdout.readline()` should have worked.  Note that the `"&"` in your command line is pointless, it's just supplying an unused parameter to Python itself.  Only if you had started the process with `shell=True` would it mean to run in the background - but that's not what you want here.

Answer (score 0):

I have to the conclusion that this problem in unsolvable. I give myself an explenation of this but I don't know if is the right answer.
The idea comes to me when I tried to redirect the out stream into a file and then read the file. The problem with this approach is that you cannot read the file if it is still open and I cannot close the file if the process is still running. If I understood correctly Linux (and so Raspbian) is a file-based OS so reading from an open "stdout" is like to reading from file opened from another process.
Again, this is the explenation that I give to myself and I do not know if is correct. Maybe one that have more knowledge about Linux OS can tell if this explenation make sense or if it is wrong.